# Using the "\s" escape sequence in terminal breaks my input

Tags: terminal, bluetooth

This is one of the stranger problems I've dealt with on MacOS. Configuration info:

- Macbook Pro - M1
- MacOS 13.6.3 (Ventura)
- Stock Terminal with no customizations

Whenever I use `grep -E` or in standard mode with escape sequences (e.g. `\s`), the following happens for about 15-20 seconds:

- Keyboard input stops working on both built-in and bluetooth keyboard
- Bluetooth keyboard and trackpad both disconnect (not just stop working, I get a disconnected message)
- Beach ball appears when cursor is over terminal window
- Notifications are blocked (any that come in will be held until this issue resolves)

After a few seconds, the issue resolves itself, my devices re-connect, and output from the terminal appears as normal.

Likely related: I'm working on a script and using ANSI escape sequences to format some of the output. After a reboot, the problem goes away and doesn't re-appear until I run the script again. Quiting and restarting Terminal.app does not resolve the problem.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

---

EDIT: I confirmed it's not the ANSI sequences. Possibly a MacOS bug, as a colleague was able to reproduce the problem on their M2 Mac running MacOS 13.6.3, but another on Sonoma was not able to reproduce it. I will submit feedback to Apple, but if anyone has any insight I'd love to hear it.

Comment: What does backslash-s represent (what is it meant to be escaping)?  A quick Google finds several contradictory representations.

Comment: That is the regex for whitespace. so `echo "hello world" | grep -E "\s"` should match the line because of the space (and it does, when the output eventually appears).